# Error when calling asmx endpoint on server with TLS 1.3 only

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asmx

I have an application that calls an ASMX web service which is situated on another server.
Recently, this server had been reconfigured to disable all TLS versions except for 1.3. This resulted in my application failing to call the ASMX with the following error:

```
Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority '[website]'.
```

The application was compiled under .NET 4.5 which doesnt have an option to specify to use TLS 1.3. So i recompiled it under 4.8 with the relevant specification to use TLS1.3:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
var basicHttpBinding = get_binding(); //returns either basicHTTpsBinding or basicHttpBinding 
        

basicHttpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = maxBufferPoolSize;
basicHttpBinding.MaxBufferSize = maxBufferSize;
basicHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxReceivedMessageSize;

String webServicesEndpointAddress = "url"
var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(webServicesEndpointAddress);
new ChannelFactory<customType>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel();
var webServices = new webserviceSoapClient(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
...
//code to call one of the web service functions
```

This however now results in a new error:

```
"An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to [url] This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. 
This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.
enter code here
```

Any ideas what could be causing the above error? I am running the application locally in visual studio over windows 10